# Windows 7 screen messed up

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card

My screen is suddenly divided in three equally large parts with a large black area in between. This is itself pretty annoying. But they also come in the wrong order: part 3, part 2 part 1.

Did I do something myself or is the graphic card ruined.

[image]

EDIT

When I plug in an extra screen the extra screen looks normal and the internal is still messed.

Comment: Check to make sure everything in plugged in firmly.

Comment: This is a laptop so there is nothing to be plugged

Comment: Not even the ribbon cable from the TFT to the motherboard?

Comment: I would prefer not to open the computer

Comment: Does this only happen while windows is running, or on the BIOS screen as well?

Comment: try wiggling the screen around. If it gets worse/better, then it's the TFT ribbon on your motherboard.

Comment: looks fun to write a question on it. :D

Comment: have you tried rebooting? (I love these standard helpdesk questions)

Answer (score 1):

try ***WINDOWS + P*** keyboard shortcut several times to turn on-off the monitor.
Can you change the screen resolution ?